# Define explicit generic methods in Swift

Tags: c++, templates, generics, swift

In C++, I can do this:

```
class foo {
    template <class bar>
    bar baz() {
        return bar()
    }
}
```

But when I try this in Swift:

```
class Foo {
    func baz<Bar>() -> Bar {
        return Bar()
    }
}
```

I got a syntax error that Swift does not support explicit generic method specialization.

Is there any similar implementations in Swift?

Comment: Why should something work in Swift just because it works in C++? Those are different languages.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I know but it's truly necessary for me. Is there any solutions exists?

Comment: @Msr.B Can you give a reason why this would be necessary?

Comment: @awesomeyi: I'm trying to implement a factory method in order to reduce duplicated codes. It's the old version: 'class func fetchManagedObjectOfClass(Class: AnyClass, templateName: String, ID: NSNumber, ...) -> NSManagedObject!'.

Comment: @awesomeyi: It doesn't meet my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly the code in C++ does. But you might use [Type Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_286).

However still it does not make sense to me, because not each class has constructor with no parameters in Swift. So I came up with this code, but I am not sure if that helps:

```
protocol TypeWithEmptyConstructor {
    init()
}

class SomeClass {
    required init() {
    }
}

extension SomeClass: TypeWithEmptyConstructor { }

class Foo {
    func baz<Bar: TypeWithEmptyConstructor>() -> Bar {
        return Bar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I run into the same problem. The solution I found was to create a dummy class whose instances are passed to my function (similarly to C++ overloading).

```
// the dummy class
class Type2Type<T> {
    typealias type = T
}

// the generic function
func myFunction<T>(Type2Type<T>) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

and call the function as

```
myFunction(Type2Type<myClass>())
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Swift expert by any means, but if you can't specialize at compile time then you have to specialize at runtime.  Swift does have some reflection features, so try something like:

```
class Foo {
    func baz<T>() -> T {
        if(T.Type == Bar) {
            doOneThing()
        } else {
            doTheOtherThing()
        }
    }
}
```

That code is untested, and might not work.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry it may not be the expected one. I just don't want to do type checking, and write 'as' syntax, especially when working with closures. You know, converting '(NSManagedObject) -> Void' to '(T) -> Void' is a little bit complex.